# AWS EC2 - 1/2 checks passed Error. Instance reachability check failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2, django

I have a Ubuntu-20.4 ec2 instance. In that, I'm running a Django Application connected with Apache Server. I created this instance 20 days back and have never stopped the instance until yesterday. Suddenly today I cannot start the instance because of the Status Check error. Is this error coming because I stopped the instance without stopping the Apache server on the instance? Please guide me on how to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: Try this suggestion - create a new instance and mount the old drive as a data drive https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664340/ubuntu-aws-instance-reachability-check-failed